# Getting this error when trying to find the VIF of dataframe

Tags: pandas, scikit-learn

```
from statsmodels.stats.outliers_influence import variance_inflation_factor
vif = pd.DataFrame()
columns = list(telecom.columns)
vif['Columns'] = columns
vif["VIF"] = [variance_inflation_factor(X, i) for i in range(len(columns))]
```

Telecom is the name of the dataframe
TypeError: '(slice(None, None, None), 0)' is an invalid key

Comment: Hi, welcome on stackoverflow :-)!  You should change your tags as it concerns mainly statsmodels and not scikit-learn (and pandas to a small extent). It would be beneficial if we could access your data such that we can reproduce your problem.

Have a look to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20159305/5304366

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.